# finding the tty of a logged in user

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to find the `tty` number of a person logging in using loops. my code so far is:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: mon user"
  exit 1
fi

user="$1"

#


until who | grep "^$user " > /dev/null
do
  tty=$(who | cut -c 9-13)
  sleep 60
done

echo "$user has logged onto $tty"
```

How would I go about only cutting out characters between 9-13 only in the first row? Secondly, did I do this correctly? I can't really test without having a person to work with.

Comment: why can't  you test on your own userID? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the code a lot as the loops are not really required to seach an extract the `user` and `tty`

For example

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
then
echo "Usage: mon user"
exit 1
fi

tty=$(who | grep "$user" | awk '{print $2}')

echo "$user has logged onto $tty"
```

**What it does?**

- `who` lists the logged in users
- `grep "$user"` searches for the lines containing `$user`
- `awk '{print $2}'` awk prints the second column in the who output

You can also use `cut` instead of `awk` as in the program. But instead of using `-c` option which selects characters use `-f` option which would select fields

That is like

```
 who | grep "$user" | cut -d\  -f 2
```

- `-d\` sets the delimtter to space
- `-f 2` selects the second field from the output

Comment: note the O.P.s name for their script, `mon`. I think they want to "watch" for someone to login (as well as get the tty), but you have answered the question posted in the headline!

Comment: @shellter Yeah infact i thought of that too. anyways the answer would do the trick :)

Comment: You did answer my question I wanted answered. I just added a lot of obsolete information with it.